# MongoDB and Arctic

Tags: database

I intend to analyse multiple data sets on the same time series (daily EOD). I will need to use computed columns. Use column A + B to create column C (store net result of calculation in column C). Is this functionality available using the MongoDB / Arctic database?

I would also intend to search the data... for example: What happens when the advance decline thrust pushes over 70 when the cumulative TICK was below -100,000 in the past 'n days'

Two data sets: Cumulative TICK and the Advance Decline Thrust (Uses advancers / decliners data). So they would be stored in the database, then I would want to have the capability to search for the above condition. This is achievable with the mongoDB / Arctic database structure?

Just looking for some general information before I move to a DB format. Currently everything I had created is on excel / VBA now its alrady out grown!

Any information greatly appreciated.

Note: I will use the same database for weekly, monthly, yearly and 1 minute, 3 minute, 5 minute 60 minute TICK/TIME based bars - not feeding live but updated EOD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a question better suited for stack overflow. I also don't see the direct link to quantitative finance. Though you refer to financial time series data, you could equally replace "stock prices" by "temperature measurements" without changing the nature of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, this can be done with arctic. Arctic can store pandas dataframes, and an operation like you have mentioned is trivial in pandas. Arctic is just a store, so you'd want to read the data out of arctic (data is stored in symbols in arctic) and then perform your transform, and then write the data back. Any of the storage engines (VersionStore, TickStore, or ChunkStore) should work for this.